# where is transparent view in luxrender

Tags: rendering, luxrender-render-engine

I use the transparent view in blender with Cycles a lot and I just started using LUXrender and I need to enable transparent view in the viewport except, I can't find it. Is this an option in Luxrender?

Comment: @RobertGützkow The linked post only refers to rendering in standalone LuxCore, after exporting the scene to the LuxCore scene format. Inside Blender, it is possible to use the "transparent film" option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select the camera, open the camera properties, and scroll down to the "Image Pipeline" panel.
In there, you can enable the "Transparent Film" option.

[image]